# How to prevent ajax get from refreshing MVC page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is my javascript

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        _rnd: new Date().getTime()
    },
    url: '@Url.Content("~/Home/RegisterDevice")' + '?name=' + '@Session["username"]' + '&phonenumber=' + $("#phonenumberInput").val() + '&imei=' + $("#imeiInput").val(),
    dataType: 'json',
    async: 'true',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        //$("#regdiv").hide();
        //$("#resdiv").append(data);
        //$("#resdiv").show();
        return false;
    }
});
```

My html has a button to trigger the javasript

```
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="RegisterDeviceDetails()">Fortsätt</button>
```

My MVC Controller has some logic and returns SUCCESS OR FAIL.

```
return Json("SUCCESS", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

My problem is that the page refreshes, so the appended response is removed as its refresh. How can i prevent the refresh?

Comment: return false in RegisterDeviceDetails method or preventDefault , change button to input type=button

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't mix inline event handlers with jQuery. It separates the event registration from the event code for no good reason and stops extra jQuery event features from working (multiple events etc)

Suggest adding an id to your button for easy access:

```
<button id="register" class="btn btn-success">Fortsätt</button>
```

Then use a standard jQuery event handler:

```
$('#register').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    RegisterDeviceDetails();
});
```

`e.preventDefault()` will stop the default button behaviour.

You can also use return false here:

```
$('#register').click(function(e){
    RegisterDeviceDetails();
    return false;
});
```

`return false` in a jQuery event handler does the same as *both* `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()`.

The `return false` inside your `success` handler does nothing as the function actually returned much earlier. It simply started an async operation. `success` gets called back much later.